# How to make different customers using the same products in Bugzilla see only their own bugs?

Tags: bugzilla

There several products already created and many reported bugs into them.

Each bugzilla user should be able to access all products. 
We have users from two different customers. We want to limit each customer to see only their own bugs and no bugs from developers or other customers.

For that I created a group for each of the customers, but can't figure out how to handle the group permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to lock each bug so that only the specific person who reported it, plus your developers, can see it:**

Create a group for your developers that will be used to designate people who can see all of the bugs.  Then on each product, set that group to "Mandatory" in both the "MemberControl" and "OtherControl" columns, and make sure the Entry checkbox is not checked.  This will cause all new bugs in that product to be placed into that group, regardless of who files them.  Reporters will always be able to see their own bugs, as will anyone added to the CC list on the bug, regardless of the groups on the bug.

If you can run a query that lists the existing bugs, you can do the "Change several bugs at once" option to add the existing bugs to that group.

**If you meant to allow anyone from that customer group to be able to view any bug filed by anyone else in the same customer group:**

I suspect that would require writing an extension that hooks the bug filing process to automatically assign the customer group of the current user as the bug is filed (which wouldn't actually be that hard, but does involve a little coding).

Your developers would then need to be members of all of the customer groups, which you can do automatically by making the developers group inherit the customer groups in the group editor, and you would need to make sure your extension doesn't add customer groups on bugs filed by your developers.

Extension writing docs are at https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Extension.html, you would probably want to hook bug_end_of_create_validators for this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to accomplish this by following the instructions from this link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.bugzilla/ZA0twAkwo3k

A Product A which needs to have bugs raised by Support, Customer X and Customer Y. 
Customer X and Support sees bugs raised by Customer X 
Customer Y and Support sees bugs raised by Customer Y 
Support only sees their bugs.

Solution: 
Have two Groups CusX-Support, and CusY-Support and add users as the group name says. 
Customer X and Support in CusX-Support 
Customer Y and Support in CusY-Support

In Edit Group Controls for Product A have the below permission set.

CusX-Support  Default/NA 
CustY-Support Default/NA

After that I had to remove the already existing bugs from all groups and add them only to the group of the company I want them to belong to. This way all users from the group finally were able to see the old bugs as well.